# How to view VB.NET object properties in the debugger within a "With object" block?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

When the debugger is in break mode, I can't view the value of a variable within the current scope of a "With" block by placing the mouse pointer over the object's property. That is, in the code below, nothing happens when I hover over over ".acctProperty" to find the current value of AcctObject.acctProperty.

```
With AcctObject
...
   Dim xyz = .acctProperty
'''
End With
```

This is VB.NET in VS2015. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just type `AcctObject.acctProperty` into the Watch window.

If you can't find the watch window - then you can access it by choosing `Debug .. Windows .. Watch` from the top menu when in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. Having to type each item of interest does slow down the process of exploring for problems though.