# VB.NET - How to view object properties via mouse hover inside a 'With' block during debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Working with VB.NET in Visual Studio 2015. During debugging, is there any way to view the value of a variable inside a 'With' block by hovering with the mouse?

For example, in the code below, if I hover over **lSection** or **lSection.MomentZ** or **lSection.MomentY** or others, VS displays information about the object and/or the value of the variable (as expected).

However, if I hover over any object starting with a period (**.SectionIndex** or **.SectionLocation** or **.Mx** or **.M_y** or **.Vx**), VS will NOT show any tooltip at all.

NOTE: I am aware that I can add the the variable to a Watch window. I know there are other ways to get the value of the variable, but I want to be able to just hover with the mouse because it is literally (yes, literally) 900 million times faster.

I could only find one other question similar to this one, but the answer does not explain whether or not there is ANY possible way to enable this feature (VS setting, registry hack, 3rd party add-on, i don't care how)
[How to view VB.NET object properties in the debugger within a "With object" block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747908/how-to-view-vb-net-object-properties-in-the-debugger-within-a-with-object-bloc)

```
With mCSIDetails
    .ClearCSIResults()

    ' Section Index and Location
    .SectionIndex = lSection.ID
    .SectionLocation = Round(lSection.FracLen * mMember.Length, 3)

    ' Section forces and moments
    .P = lSection.AxialForce
    If liAxis = MemberOrientation.Strong Then
        .Mx = lSection.MomentZ
        .M_y = lSection.MomentY
        .Vx = lSection.ShearForce_CSI_12
        .Vy = lSection.ShearForceZ_CSI_12
    ElseIf liAxis = MemberOrientation.Weak Then
        .Mx = lSection.MomentY
        .M_y = lSection.MomentZ
        .Vx = lSection.ShearForceZ_CSI_12
        .Vy = lSection.ShearForce_CSI_12
    End If
End With
```

Comment: This question has some additional comments about this topic. But it still does not give a flat **YES** or **NO** answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256776/is-there-a-way-to-debug-vb-net-with-clause-in-visual-studio

Comment: Hover over `mCSIDetails` and see all the properties?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question [on the Visual Studio forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1eecff7-9b1f-4456-92f7-05fcd9f9699c/vbnet-how-to-view-object-properties-via-mouse-hover-inside-a-with-block-during-debugging?forum=vsdebug#844c049a-46b1-4c96-ae69-b5e98d4f3d29) and the moderator was able to replicate the issue.

Apparently this is just the new (terrible) way the debugger works. So if you want to be able to mouse-hover and get a tooltip with the object/variable value, then **don't** use **WITH** blocks...